# How to secure my domain site?

Tags: force.com-sites

How to secure my domain site?. i have created my domain in salesforce and i had given Require Secure Connections (HTTPS) checkbox true and i had assigned visual force pages to site. i am getting images URL with http from another server and saving in to one field. those images are displaying in my visual force page. i checked browser console its getting "mixed content" error and my site is not secure. How i need to secure the my site and also i need those another server images also. when i change those image urls with https its not display in my site. how to resolve it. can anybody help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is a known limitation of Force.com Sites. Force.com Sites do not yet support SSL for Custom Web Domain. Try using https://.secure.force.com for SSL communications.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006nxHAAQ